# Date and Time with high precision in Windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, datetime

I am new to C++ programming in Windows environment. 
I want to get the current system date and time in the below format:
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.Milliseconds using Windows C++ API.I need to capture is up to microseconds. Could you please share a sample code on how to achieve this in Windows.

Comment: Howard Hinnant has [a really neat library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) that should help you out. Or you can wait a few years for C++20.

Comment: Note that reliable microseconds can be tricky to get on Windows. It's not exactly built for high precision timing.

Comment: Precision is meaningless until you specify the required accuracy as well.

Comment: I have mentioned i need the microsecond information as well. I know how to do in Linux but since i am new to Windows i dont know how to do it. I have searched in web but unable to relate all the options. e.g. QuerryPerformanceCounter is for to get high resolution time stamps. But how to get the year month and day information using this i didnot find any concrete reference.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between precision and accuracy? Consult a dictionary if you don't, and update the question once you do.

Comment: i am sorry i confused with the terms. I will correct the question. But if you cant answer my question please dont waste my time by pointing such useless mistakes  and that to commenting in such way.

Comment: This is only useless, if you are not a developer that needs to produce a solution based on a specification. It's unclear why you need microsecond precision/accuracy, when all you want is a format, that has doesn't store microsecond information.

Comment: I added a comment and corrected my question, so i think it was clear what i need.

Answer (score 3):

Using the draft C++20 spec:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    cout << format("%d-%m-%Y %T", floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
}
```

Currently VS does not implement this, but you can get a preview by using [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  Just include it and add a using directive:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    cout << format("%d-%m-%Y %T", floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
}
```

As you asked for "system time", this delivers a UTC time stamp, as that is what your system time measures.  If you instead want local time, that is also available, but [requires some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

Sample output:

```
29-11-2018 14:45:03.679098
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `system_clock` is a very close approximation of UTC. For true UTC time points we'll have to wait until C++20 introduces [utc_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock).

Comment: `<chuckle>` I have to respect the detail with which you have studied my proposal.  If anyone would like a preview of `utc_clock`, [that too is available](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#utc_clock).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library. Look at this example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::string current_datetime()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // get current time
    auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    // get duration in milliseconds
    auto msec = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();
    msec %= 1000;

    // get printable result:
    auto now_time_t = high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&now_time_t), "%d-%m-%Y %X:") << msec;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    for(auto i = 0U;i < 1000;i++)
        std::cout << current_datetime() << std::endl;
}
```

Also it's possible to get microseconds:

```
auto mksec = duration_cast<microseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();
mksec %= 1000;
```

If you need WinAPI-specific version that's it:

```
std::string current_datetime2()
{
    FILETIME ft;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
    unsigned long long mks = static_cast<unsigned long long>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32 | ft.dwLowDateTime;
    mks /= 10; // interval in microsecond
    mks %= 1000;

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << st.wDay << "-" << st.wMonth << "-" << st.wYear << " " <<
        st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << ":" << st.wMilliseconds << ":" << mks << std::endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

or another very simple WinAPI-version, but without microseconds:

```
std::string current_datetime3()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << st.wDay << "-" << st.wMonth << "-" << st.wYear << " " <<
        st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << ":" << st.wMilliseconds;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: This I can almost get behind. Recommend adding some explanation, identifiers are well-named so not much should be required, and a few documentation links to round out the answer.

Comment: The OP explicitly asks for a solution using the Windows API. `std::chrono` is C++11, which may not be available. Besides the OP is asking for *system* time, not local time.

Comment: @IInspectable Fix it

Comment: When you need usec, shouldn't this mksec %= 1000; be this mksec %= 1000000; ??

Answer (score -1):

on windows platform:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st);
TCHAR buf[128];
_stprintf_s(buf, _ARRAYSIZE(buf),
    _T("%04u-%02u%-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u.%03u"),
    st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay,
    st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

will fulfill most cases. If you want to get more accurate timespan, use

QueryPerformanceFrequency, 
  QueryPerformanceCounter;

Comment: Downvote is probably because milliseconds, not microseconds. Could also be because it's 2018 and TCHAR was a hack solution to a Win9x-Winnt portability problem from back around 1998.

Comment: @user4581301 It's not "a hack", it's "a core hack". You were supposed to use it back in 1995, nobody called that order off, so it still stands. All API methods are defined with TCHAR.

Comment: @age: Incorrect. The API has explicit exports for ANSI and Unicode. The SDK headers provide macros for genetic-text mappings. Those are resolved at compile time. The linker doesn't know `TCHAR`s. Probably what you meant to say, but failed to express.

Comment: thank you give me reason why it is downvoted, while the question author is asking for microseconds ( in 0.000001 second ), and the question's description misleading me. and on linux os, the c-runtime api will return microsecond.